# MDX Start and End Time per transaction

Tags: ssas, mdx, cubes

I hope you can help i have tried so many way to try get this right with no luck. I am trying to get out the player account number the date and start and end date time and maybe calculate the play duration between the start and end times.

I would like the output to look something like this.

> PlayerAccount | GamingDate | StartTime | EndTime | PlayDuration | ActualWin

I always seem to return the start and end time for the whole day and not Per account.

```
 WITH 
  SET [MySet] AS 
      [Customer].[Player Account Number].Children*
      Head
      (
        NonEmpty
        (
          [Start Time].[Hour].Children
         ,[Measures].[Actual Win]
        )
       ,1
      )*
      Tail
      (
        NonEmpty
        (
          [End Time].[Hour].Children
         ,[Measures].[Actual Win]
        )
       ,1
      ) 
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[Actual Win]} ON 0
 ,{[MySet]} ON 1
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
      [Customer].[Player Account Number].&[1040002184]
    : 
      [Customer].[Player Account Number].&[1040002198] ON 0
  FROM Ratings
)
WHERE 
  {[Gaming Date].[Full Date].&[20150101]};
```

Comment: Check my attempt pls.

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti I'm a bit unsure about this approach - traditionally firstdates or lastdates, or lastdatesWithdata are done using `[MEASURES]`. So although interesting I think it is better to not use a custom set?

Comment: You are absolutely right mate. Ideally we should have measures doing this job. That's the reason why my approach also didn't work.

Comment: The AdvWrks Measures approach I've added in my answer works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually first date and last date would be measures. If you only want results for those two player then use the WHERE clause rather than a sub-select:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[fDate] AS 
    Head
    (
      NonEmpty
      (
        [Start Time].[Hour].MEMBERS
       ,[Measures].[Actual Win]
      )
    ).Item(0).Item(0).Member_Caption 
  MEMBER [Measures].[lDate] AS 
    Tail
    (
      NonEmpty
      (
        [End Time].[Hour].MEMBERS
       ,[Measures].[Actual Win]
      )
    ).Item(0).Item(0).Member_Caption 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[fDate]
   ,[Measures].[lDate]
   ,[Measures].[Actual Win]
  } ON 0
 ,{[Customer].[Player Account Number].Children} ON 1
FROM Ratings
WHERE 
  ([Gaming Date].[Full Date].&[20150101],
   { [Customer].[Player Account Number].&[1040002184]
    ,[Customer].[Player Account Number].&[1040002198]});
```

This is a working `AdvWrks` script which does the sort of thing you're trying to achieve:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[firstDate] AS 
    Head
    (
      NonEmpty
      (
        [Date].[Date].[Date].MEMBERS
       ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
      )
    ).Item(0).Item(0).Member_Caption 
  MEMBER [Measures].[lastDate] AS 
    Tail
    (
      NonEmpty
      (
        [Date].[Date].[Date].MEMBERS
       ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
      )
    ).Item(0).Item(0).Member_Caption 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
   ,[Measures].[firstDate]
   ,[Measures].[lastDate]
  } ON 0
 ,NON EMPTY {[Promotion].[Promotion].MEMBERS} ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

If you'd rather pull back a member instead of using Measures I think the `GENERATE` function will work like this AdvWrks example:

```
WITH 
  SET [aSet] AS 
    Generate
    (
      [Promotion].[Promotion].MEMBERS
     ,
        [Promotion].[Promotion].CurrentMember
      * 
        Head
        (
          NonEmpty
          (
            [Date].[Date].[Date].MEMBERS
           ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
          )
        )
    ) 
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]} ON 0
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {[aSet]} ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Comment: I guess you need to put `EXISTING` around the `[Customer].[Player Account Number].children` not on the dates as they are not sliced.

Comment: I'm new to using `EXISTING` but I know that it pull the cellset context into the `WITH` clause - so I've added `[Customer].[Player Account Number].children` into the cellset and then used `EXISTING` to pull that context into the `WITH` clause?

Comment: I will review this and comment back.

Comment: I have tried adding the existing from both of your examples and I still get the same result, Im sure it has something to do with my set but totally lost here, pretty new to MDX, so much easier the TSql

Comment: @smckechnie - my first script was rubbish as just tested against AdvWrks, so I've deleted it. I'm working on testing the second.

Comment: I still get the following result back
1040002184 Hour 0 Hour 23 (null)
1040002198 Hour 0 Hour 23 (null)

Comment: @smckechnie is `1040002184 Hour 0 Hour 23 (null) 1040002198 Hour 0 Hour 23 (null) ` not the correct result? Please remember you have `[Gaming Date].[Full Date].&[20150101]` in the `WHERE` clause so the result you are getting is the first and last hour on the 1st of jan 2015

Comment: @smckechnie I've amended the first script a little to try to simplify - If it is only those two accounts you're interested in then maybe simpler to the the WHERE clause.

Comment: The correct result should be something like 1040002184 Hour 0 Hour 5 (duration 5 hours) , 1040002198 Hour 21 hour 23 (Duration 3 hours) but it seems to take Hour 0 and hour 23 for both records.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a million whytheq it seems like that .Item(0).Item(0).Member_Caption made all the difference the results seem to be come out right now. The final solution looks like this now..

```
with set [MySet]
as
[Casino Hierarchy].[Casino Key].children *
[Gaming Date].[Date].currentmember * 
[Customer].[Player Account Number].children *
[Start Time].[Hour].children

member [measures].[Mindate]
as
HEAD(nonempty([End Time].[Hour].children,[Measures].[Actual Win]),1).Item(0).Item(0).Member_Caption 

member [measures].[Maxdate]
as
TAIL(nonempty([Start Time].[Hour].children,[Measures].[Actual Win]),1).Item(0).Item(0).Member_Caption 

    select non empty
    {
    [Measures].[Actual Win],[measures].[Mindate],[measures].[Maxdate]
    } on 0, non empty
    { 
    [Customer].[Player Account Number].children
    } on 1
    from
    (
    select  ([Customer].[Player Account Number].&[1040002184]:[Customer].[Player Account Number].&[1040002198])  on 0 from Ratings
    )
    where 
    {
    [Gaming Date].[Full Date].&[20150101]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having a static set(which always return the same members). Use the `EXISTING` keyword to evaluate the Start and end time in the current context.

```
with member [Measures].[StartDate] as

    EXISTING    
    HEAD(
            nonempty(
                    [Start Time].[Hour].Children,[Measures].[Actual Win]
                    ) ,1
        ).ITEM(0).ITEM(0).MEMBERVALUE



member [Measures].[EndDate] as
    EXISTING
    TAIL(
            nonempty(
                    [End Time].[Hour].children,[Measures].[Actual Win]
                    ) ,1            
        ).ITEM(0).ITEM(0).MEMBERVALUE       


select 
    {
    [Measures].[Actual Win], 
    [Measures].[StartDate], 
    [Measures].[EndDate]
    } on 0,

    [Customer].[Player Account Number].children on 1

from
(
    select  (
            [Customer].[Player Account Number].&[1040002184]:
            [Customer].[Player Account Number].&[1040002198]
            )  on 0 
    from Ratings
)

where {[Gaming Date].[Full Date].&[20150101]}
```

Have rearranged the `[Customer].[Player Account Number]` so that dates are evaluated in the context of each player account. Hope that's fine!

Edit.

A simplified AdWrks version of this approach is as follows: still not quite working:

```
WITH 
  SET [aSet] AS 
    (EXISTING 
      Head
      (
        NonEmpty
        (
          [Date].[Date].[Date].MEMBERS
         ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
        )
      )) 
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]} ON 0
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {[Promotion].[Promotion].MEMBERS * [aSet]} ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Comment: Thank @Sourav_Agasti. The solution works perfectly if I have one Player account, but the moment a have a list of accounts it returns the first hour for the entire list and the last hour for the entire list and not for each Player Account

Comment: sourav - I have an AdvWrks equiv of your script if you want to play with it? (I could add to your answer if you like?) ... I'm interested to know if you can get this approach to work.

Comment: @Sourav Your edited code returns errors in the measures

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti - I've added the simplied version of AdvWrks model. If you can get this working it would be good - I think a quicker solution than using `member_caption`.

Comment: @smckechnie - I forgot to add an `ITEM(0).ITEM(0)`. Have added the same now